# Is there a much more cleaner and shorter way to check if string is empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on my express server and I am trying to validate some query parameters. For example I can have query parameter `date` which might be null or be an empty string. Now the current validation is like this

```
if(req.query.date && req.query.date !== '')
```

Is there like a function or a library that I can use like `_lodash` to keep things more neat?

Comment: you can try https://validatejs.org/

Comment: If that date is a string or null, then both conditions will give the same result, so you can reduce it to the first.

Comment: Do you need the `if` for something? What happens in the `if` block?

Comment: See this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5572/string-isnullorempty-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is already neat, you can just simplify it to

```
if(req.query.date)
```

Try not overuse `lodash` or other packages, you can write these things by yourself, but all these redundant packages just flood your bundle and make it heavier.